# How can I iterate through 2 divs in the same time?

Tags: php, html, loops, iteration

I am trying to iterate through 2 divs at the same time to echo out data from the database. Each div has it's own style and I want to keep iterating without duplicate each div twice, without losing my divs style. Even when I delete any post from my database, I don't want to lose div design Arrangement (odd/even display), any help or advice?

```
// class getAll to get all posts from db tables

class getALL { 
  private $pdo;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->pdo = db::getInstance();
  }

  public function get() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts`";
    $q = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute();
    if($q->rowCount()) {
      return $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
    return false;
  } 
}
```

**here the part of the 2 divs**

```
// the 2 divs with iteration

<? if(is_array($getArticles) || is_object($getArticles)): ?>
<? foreach($getArticles as $getArticle): ?>
<? if($getArticle->id % 2 == 0) { ?>  //odd/even logic 
    <!-- One -->
        <article id="one" class="post style1">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="<?='images/'.$getArticle->image_name?>" alt="" data-position="75% center" />
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="inner">
                    <header>
                        <h2><a href="post.html"><?=$getArticle->title?></a></h2>
                        <p class="info"><?=$getArticle->post_time?> by <a href="#"><?=$getArticle->username?></a></p>
                    </header>
                    <p><?=$getArticle->post?></p>
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li><a href="post.php" class="button alt">Read More</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>

<? }else{ ?>

    <!-- two -->
        <article id="four" class="post invert style2 alt">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="<?='images/'.$getArticle->image_name?>" alt="" data-position="60% center" />
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="inner">
                    <header>
                        <h2><a href="post.php"><?=$getArticle->title?></a></h2>
                        <p class="info"><?=$getArticle->post_time?> by <a href="#"><?=$getArticle->username?></a></p>
                    </header>
                    <p><?=$getArticle->post?></p>
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li><a href="post.php" class="button alt">Read More</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>

<? } ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: is it only the class change that is different?  If so you can just style them using `:nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)`.  Also your loop is going to cause duplicated ids

Comment: this code is working fine but the problem is when i try to delete post from database odd/even numbers for posts id destroy the div Arrangement and the style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$getArticle->id`, use a simple `$counter` variable to combine two divs together and to implement odd-even logic. That way, when you delete a post, it won't destroy the div arrangement. Here's **the solution**:

```
<?php $counter = 0; ?>
<?php if(is_array($getArticles) || is_object($getArticles)): ?>
<?php foreach($getArticles as $getArticle): ?>

<article id=<?php if($counter % 2 == 0){ echo "one"; }else{ echo "four"; } ?> class="post<?php if($counter % 2 == 0){ echo " style1"; }else{ echo " invert style2 alt"; } ?>">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="<?='images/'.$getArticle->image_name?>" alt="" data-position="<?php if($counter % 2 == 0){ echo "75%"; }else{ echo "60%"; } ?> center" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="inner">
            <header>
                <h2><a href="post.php"><?=$getArticle->title?></a></h2>
                <p class="info"><?=$getArticle->post_time?> by <a href="#"><?=$getArticle->username?></a></p>
            </header>
            <p><?=$getArticle->post?></p>
            <ul class="actions">
                <li><a href="post.php" class="button alt">Read More</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>

<?php ++$counter; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thnX a lot that's helped me well

Comment: @MostafaEsmat You're welcome! Please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)